# defining a collection that accepts any implementation of generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic abstract class `Plot<T>`. How can I define a collection that will accept any implementation of the abstract class? I have tried the following approaches without success:

`public List<Plot<object>> Plots = new List<Plot<object>>();`

`public List<Plot<dynamic>> Plots = new List<Plot<dynamic>>();`

Thanks.

Comment: `class PlotList<T> : List<Plot<T>> { }`

Comment: You can't create this collection because generics in C# are defined at compile-time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Situations like this usually call for creating a non-generic base class, from which the generic class derives:

```
public abstract class Plot
{
    // Put anything which doesn't need T here
}

public class Plot<T> : Plot
{
}
```

Then you can create a `List<Plot>`.

Comment: I've used this technique myself in many projects I've done. I first came across this in the book Domain Driven Design by Tim McCarthy. http://www.amazon.com/NET-Domain-Driven-Design-Problem-Solution/dp/0470147563/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1365533533&sr=8-5&keywords=domain+driven+design